# Can't install "libdvdcss" with yum anymore after update on "Fedora 20 Heisenburg"

Tags: fedora, software-installation, package-management, yum, dvd

I couldn't update my system today, because of dependency problems with `libdvdcss`, I removed `libdvdcss` and it's dependency `libdvdcss2`. Update was successfull after that but now I can't install `libdvdcss` back, because it's not in the repositories.

```
Dependencies Resolved

===================================================================================
 Package             Arch            Version                Repository        Size
===================================================================================
Removing:
 libdvdcss2          x86_64          1.2.13-7.fc20          @atrpms           34 k
Removing for dependencies:
 libdvdcss           x86_64          1.2.13-7.fc20          @atrpms           98 k

Transaction Summary
===================================================================================
Remove  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................

```
~]$ sudo yum install libdvdcss
.......

No package libdvdcss available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

....................................................................................................................................................................

```
~]$ sudo yum repolist
[sudo] password for user: 
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, fastestmirror, langpacks, refresh-
              : packagekit, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: www.fedora.is
 * fedora-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: www.fedora.is
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
 * updates: www.fedora.is
 * updates-debuginfo: www.fedora.is
repo id                                       repo name                      status
adobe-linux-i386                              Adobe Systems Incorporated          2
adobe-linux-x86_64                            Adobe Systems Incorporated          2
fedora/20/x86_64                              Fedora 20 - x86_64             38,597
fedora-debuginfo/20/x86_64                    Fedora 20 - x86_64 - Debug      6,881
home_tpokorra_mono                            mono and monodevelop (Fedora_2     89
mysql-connectors-community/20/x86_64          MySQL Connectors Community         13
mysql-tools-community/20/x86_64               MySQL Tools Community              10
mysql56-community/20/x86_64                   MySQL 5.6 Community Server         73
rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64                      RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Fre    468
rpmfusion-free-debuginfo/20/x86_64            RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Fre    166
rpmfusion-free-updates/20/x86_64              RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Fre    402
rpmfusion-free-updates-debuginfo/20/x86_64    RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Fre    132
rpmfusion-nonfree/20/x86_64                   RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Non    203
rpmfusion-nonfree-debuginfo/20/x86_64         RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Non     60
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64           RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Non    288
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-debuginfo/20/x86_64 RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Non    113
tor/x86_64                                    Tor experimental repo               2
tor-source                                    Tor experimental source repo        0
updates/20/x86_64                             Fedora 20 - x86_64 - Updates   18,678
updates-debuginfo/20/x86_64                   Fedora 20 - x86_64 - Updates -  2,405
virtualbox/20/x86_64                          Fedora 20 - x86_64 - VirtualBo      9
```

From rpmfind.net [link](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdvdcss&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=):

> libdvdcss is a simple library designed for accessing
>   DVDs as a block device without having to bother about the decryption.

What has happened?

Do I lose the ability to play dvd's for some time or have they changed something so it comes from somewhere else?

EDIT:
It seems that I originally installed it with `yum` from the `atrpms` repository following [this](http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f16.html) guide. I thought it should have been standard for `rpmfusion` but it didn't come from there.

Comment: `yum search libdvdcss`? You can install libdvdcss from source if you have to. But there should be third party packages available for fedora if they are not available in the official repositories.

Comment: @FaheemMitha My understanding is that it came with/from rpmfusion. I installed it with yum a while back.

Comment: Well, do a search online. If necessary, you could build your own rpm using older rpm packaging. See the source tarballs at http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html

Comment: It's available from [atrpms.net](http://atrpms.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my own question with:

> Update was successfull after that but now I can't install libdvdcss
>   back, because it's not in the repositories.
>
> What has happened?

Follow the directions on [this](http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f16.html) site for installing audio, video and dvd support on your Fedora.

---

**Exerpt from http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-f16.html for installing `libdvdcss` on Fedora:**

DVD Playback - The libdvdcss is required for DVD playback. Due to non-technical reasons, the package does not exist in the RPMFusion repository. For only this package an alternate repository will be used.

```
Please use the ATrpms Repository:

[mirandam@charon Download]$ wget http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/files/atrpms.repo
[mirandam@charon Download]$ sudo cp ./atrpms.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/atrpms.repo
[mirandam@charon Download]$ sudo rpm --import http://packages.atrpms.net/RPM-GPG-KEY.atrpms

To install the package:

[mirandam@charon ~]$ sudo yum --enablerepo=atrpms install libdvdcss

NOTE ATrpms may conflict with RPMFusion hence it is kept disabled. Previously the Livna Repository was used for this however Livna has been unreliable.
```

UPDATE #1

I've been downloading this package from [rpmfind](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdvdcss&submit=Search%20...) since this stopped working, hope it can assist anyone in the future.(and also this one: [libdvdread](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdvdread&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=))

Comment: This is not working anymore, don't know if it will again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to just clone the project from the repository, from the project page: http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html - copying an "autogen.sh" file from some other project, as it seens to be missing, then running `autogen.sh --prefix=/usr; make; sudo make install`.

Fedora's mplayer could them see and reproduce a DVD - but not the system-installed VLC.